# There exists an $\aleph_0$-coloring of a graph on the real numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I have this question:

> Let $G = ( \mathbb{R} , E)$  be a graph such that its vertices are the real numbers and its edge set is given by $$E = \big\{ \{u,v\}\,\big |\, u-v \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0 \}\big\}\,.$$
> Prove that the graph has a legal coloring in color set $\mathbb{N}$.

I have a graph $G$ with vertices set $V$,
If there is a legal coloring of the graph $G$ using a set $A$ of colors of cardinality of $a$. Does that mean there is a legal coloring of $G$ using **every** set of colors with cardinality $a$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: If there’s a legal coloring with one set of $a$ colors, there is a legal coloring with **any** set of $a$ colors.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Even if the cardinalities of both sets are infinite? (like aleph's) ? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. If the two sets of colors are $A$ and $B$, there is a bijection $f:A\to B$; given a legal coloring using $A$, just replace each color $a\in A$ with its image color $f(a)$ in $B$.

Comment: What is a "legal coloring" of a graph? Do you color the vertices, or the edges, or vertices and edges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Show that if $\{u,v\}$ and $\{v,w\}$ are both edges of $G$, then $\{u,w\}$ is also an edge of $G$. Conclude that each component of $G$ is a countably infinite complete graph.

**Added:** I’ll fill in a bit more detail.

Let $u$ be any vertex of $G$; the neighborhood of $u$ (i.e., $u$ together with the set of vertices to which it is joined by edges) is $N(u)=\{u\pm q:q\in\Bbb Q\}$. Note that this is a countably infinite set (why?). Use the original hint to show that if $v\in N(u)$, then $N(v)=N(u)$: every vertex in $N(u)$ is connected by an edge to every other vertex in $N(u)$, and no vertex in $N(u)$ is connected to any vertex outside of $N(u)$. That shows that $N(u)$ is both a complete subgraph of $G$ and a component of $G$. And it has countably infinitely many vertices, so there is a bijection between it and $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am still stuck on that $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$ - why did they remove the $0$ ? This makes me go insane!

Comment: @OnAndOff: That’s so that $G$ has no loops. If you allowed $0$, each vertex of $G$ would have a loop, i.e., an edge from that vertex to itself.

Comment: Doesn't that just proving there is transitive property in $\mathbb{Q}$ ? Because I think there isn't : $ u = 1, w = \sqrt{2}, v = 2$ I would appreciate if you could correct me!

Comment: @OnAndOff: There is no edge between $1$ and $\sqrt2$ or between $2$ and $\sqrt2$, because $1-\sqrt2$ and $2-\sqrt2$ are irrational. The only edge among your three vertices is between $1$ and $2$.

Comment: But how does each connected component is a countably infinite complete graph? if my graph like a square and another square (not connected) they are both not complete

Comment: @OnAndOff: But in this case each component **is** complete. Here’s a further hint: one of the components is $\Bbb Q$ itself: $p-q$ is rational whenever $p$ and $q$ are rational, so each vertex in $\Bbb Q$ has an edge to each other vertex in $\Bbb Q$. And if $q\in\Bbb Q$ and $x$ is **irrational**, then $q-x\notin\Bbb Q$, so no rational vertex is connected by an edge to any irrational vertex.

Comment: But if I understood correctly and proved transitive property for $\mathbb{Q}$ then how do I continue? this is frustrating as I know I got this... I mean if it is infinite complete graph (countable) then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: @OnAndOff: $\Bbb N$ by itself isn’t a graph, so a component of $G$ can’t be isomorphic to it. However, if we let $\Bbb E$ be the set of all unordered pairs of natural numbers, then $\langle\Bbb N,\Bbb E\rangle$ is a complete graph on countably infinitely many vertices, and every component of $G$ is isomorphic to that graph. Any bijection from the vertex set of the component to $\Bbb N$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have a little question, how did you conclude transitive property ? (The $\{u,v\} - \{v,w\} \rightarrow \{u, w\}$ is it concluded from the transitive property of $\mathbb{Q}$ ? Because this is something I did not yet prove (that Q is transitive) is it just an easy - sided proof?

Comment: @OnAndOff: If $u-v\in\Bbb Q$ and $v-w\in\Bbb Q$, their sum is also in $\Bbb Q$: the sum of any two rational numbers is rational. And their sum is $(u-v)+(v-w)=u-w$, so $u-w\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @OnAndOff: You’re very welcome!